# How to stop the Pop up of chrome that save Password

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am using Google Chrome and Application of Angular when I log in to my angular application I want not to show the popup of saving password by google chrome what code or logic should I use to stop that save password popup.

Comment: Try `autocomplete="off"` for your input

Comment: i have tried autocomplete="off" but it is not working is there is any another way to stop the save password popup

Comment: I think you can't disable this popup for everyone, as it's a browser feature. But you can disable it for you by following [this guide](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23945619/how-to-disable-the-password-checkup-in-chrome?hl=en).

Comment: Oh right, chrome has been ignoring this for years. You can change type to "text", but the password will be visible..

Comment: But i  have to use the Jaws software when i am using type to "text" jaws started reading that password also i want Jaws to not read the password

Comment: I have problem recognizing how the question is related to the Java Programming Language? Did you eventually mean Javascript, totally different from Java?